# Up go the bits!

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

Given an integer N perform the following steps: (using 9 as an example).

1. Receive input N. (`9`)
2. Convert N from base10 to base2. (`1001`)
3. Increase every bit by 1. (`2112`)
4. Treat the result as base3 and convert it back to base10. (`68`)
5. Return/Output the result.

---

### Input

May be received in any reasonable number format.
You only need to handle cases where N > 0.

---

### Output

Either return as a number or string, or print to `stdout`.

---

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.
- Default loopholes are forbidden.

---

### Test Cases

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 7
5 -> 23
9 -> 68
10 -> 70
20 -> 211
1235 -> 150623
93825 -> 114252161
```

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and 3*f(n/2)+n%2+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoMwFAXX9hRvEzT1l5ofAlVo75IioYI@RXTR06fpYhYzi9m@x2el5pyec1zeYwQHInKEv6aGd7UtjbYup3UHMRFOoIIg6AWuK1Jw6v/BPzQMl2rbJx6oTThxe8H0Zw2DhoIytDb/AA)

Comment: Could you explain how this works?

Comment: `+n%2+1` adds the rightmost binary bit plus 1 to the return value, `n/2` right-shifts `n` by 1 binary bit, `3*f(n/2)` recursively adds 3 times this computation on those right-shifted bits, and `n and` ends the recursion when `n` is 0

Answer (score 11):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 23 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>x&&x%2+1+3*f(x>>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcVBDkAwEADAu1f0QnYVUY60n/ACQWVFulKN9PcVcZk55me@F09XqB2vW0pWR21iUcS8k0r2pYVojMJk2QPpdhA0qvZLSsyEWNjdfG7NyTtQJSwQ/jaBp@DJ7dAjDukF)

Comment: `x>>1` is the same as `x/2` isn't it?

Comment: @mbomb007 I thought and suggested the same just yet, but apparently it becomes `Infinity` in JS.. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbC1q5CTa1C1UjbUNtYK02jQt9I839afpFGpq2BtUKmjaEBiNLW1uRSUEjOzyvOz0nVy8lP18jUUUjTyNTUtP4PAA) (You might want to add a TIO-link to you answer, _I4m2_)

Comment: @mbomb007 No. `1>>1=0` while `1/2=0.5`

Comment: Right, Python 2 uses integer division.

Comment: @mbomb007 ... Python?

Comment: Yeah. Look at the Python answer. That's the reason `n/2` works in that one, and the reason I suggested it here.

Answer (score 9):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 44 bytes

```java
long n(long x){return x<1?0:x%2+1+3*n(x/2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3LDoIwEEX3fMXExKS1irbERAXjD@jKpXFRBUkRCoGiGMK311ofC2Nc3UzuuWcSfuGjJDzrY8qrCjZcyNbRaS5jkMhGg9syUnUpoQnoarJo@oxQ4g0kasYM@512AIr6kIojVIorE5dchJAZE9qqUsh4t@e4NRRYPWSwBBld7YGwb4tTXj6/iSX1QQTUYyYIwbYF2N4qFWVuXiu3MEqFMlcigUlv2HsZvon04/7RPNaUedM1/s/MvRl7Q53T6Ts)

Comment: Maybe `-~` will help?

Comment: No, precedence rules.

Comment: Same question to you: why `long`? :) And here I thought my sequence approach was smart.. You blew it out of the park in less than 5 minutes.. >.> :'(

Comment: @KevinCruijssen To be fair with you ...

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
B‘ḅ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/pUcOMhztajf///28JAA)

Comment: Binary, Increment, To-base, 3. That's really all that needs to be said.

Comment: @Adám Technically that's **From**-base, but yes, this is trivial in most, if not all, golfing languages.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 10, <s>81</s> 52 bytes (Base conversion)

```java
n->n.toString(n,2).chars().reduce(0,(r,c)->r*3+c-47)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY7BTsMwDIbvfQprJ4e2EW2ZxlS2J9h22RFxCGk2srXOlKSbEOqzl7QFDggJKdEv279/fydxFempOveyFs7BVmj6iAA0eWUPQirYDSVAbegIEjeDECtDrws/vB0QrKCndE3cm723mo5ISc64fBPWIeNWVa1UeJ@gTSRL1/auiGX6sGB9GYWAS/taawnOCx/kanQFTaDAKer5RbCJYECDJtwidRsLHDEADsbiiKdXWQn6KSvyIHHMxinA/t151XDTen4JkR4bTlyiZvEsmX1l/PbUP@l/TKb9LC/mG/afa1k85t@2Lur6Tw)

-29 bytes thanks to *@Holger*.

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                         // Method with Long as both parameter and return-type
  n.toString(n,2)            //  Convert the input to a Base-2 String
  .chars().reduce(0,(r,c)->  //  Loop over its digits as bytes
    r*3+c-47)                //  Multiply the current result by 3, and add the digit + 1
                             //  (which is equal to increasing each digit by 1,
                             //  and then converting from Base-3 to Base-10)
```

---

## Java 10, <s>171</s> <s>167</s> <s>151</s> <s>150</s> 149 bytes (Sequence)

```java
n->{int t=31-n.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);return a(t+1)+b(n-(1<<t));};int a(int n){return--n<1?n+2:3*a(n)+1;}int b(int n){return n<1?0:n+3*b(n/=2)+n*2;}
```

-16 bytes thanks to *@musicman523*, changing `(int)Math.pow(2,t)` to `(1<<t)`.
-1 byte thanks to *@Holger*, changing `(int)(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2))` to `31-n.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY9RS8MwEMff@ymOPSWLraZF0KXVZ0Hnw94UH9IuG5nrdaTpREo/e710Q1AEIclxd7//5f47fdTxbv0@VnvdtvCkLfYRgEVv3EZXBpYhnQpQsQcqb40D5IqqA106S0AoYMT4rg@ULzIZY4JdXRr3vHk0em1x@2Jc0zLSOeM7h6CZF5KLkmHMZJ57ztWgglyz8CLvT2AcYy7vUaSLbK5JL6QaAlD@xCBQVwsU2ZxGXhYpFzhP1TCqiDY8dOXeVtB67SkcG7uGmoyylXe02uub5ieTwT3UZAbNx5SwySfApnHTf7aQCmwus5SCEHxqAqw@W2/qpOl8cqCJntUJJhWzXMwuZucRv5n99/A/Oie9TLNr/h90m92kZ2qIhvEL)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                         // Method with Integer as both parameter and return-type
  int t=31-n.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
                             //  2_log(n)
  return a(t+1)              //  Return A060816(2_log(n)+1)
         +b(n-(1<<t));}      //   + A005836(n-2^2_log(n))

// A060816: a(n) = 3*a(n-1) + 1; a(0)=1, a(1)=2
int a(int n){return--n<1?n+2:3*a(n)+1;}

// A005836: a(n+1) = 3*a(floor(n/2)) + n - 2*floor(n/2).
int b(int n){return n<1?0:n+3*b(n/=2)+n*2;}
```

When we look at the sequence:

```java
2,  7,8,  22,23,25,26,  67,68,70,71,76,77,79,80,  202,203,205,206,211,212,214,215,229,230,232,233,238,239,241,242, ...
```

We can see multiple subsequences:

```java
A053645(n):
0,  0,1,  0,1,2,3,  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,  ...

A060816(A053645(n)):
2,  7,7,  22,22,22,22,  67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,  202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,202,  ...

A005836(A053645(n)+1)
0,  0,1,  0,1,3,4,  0,1,3,4,9,10,12,13,  0,1,3,4,9,10,12,13,27,28,30,31,36,37,39,40,  ...
```

So the sequence being asked is:

```java
A060816(A053645(n)) + A005836(A053645(n)+1)
```

---

I suck at finding patterns, so I'm proud of what I found above.. Having said that, *@user202729* found [a better and shorter approach in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161625/52210) within a few minutes.. :'(

Comment: Re `n.toString(n,2).getBytes()` ... I _think_ manual conversion may be shorter.

Comment: "Arithmetic sequence" --> still use recursion?

Comment: BTW why `long` and not `int`?

Comment: @user202729 Good question, changed it to `int` and removed _arithmetic_

Comment: I think in the sequence version you can change out `(int)Math.pow(2,t)` for `1<<t`...and then inline that expression and drop the variable i ([152 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZDBboMwDIbvPIXVU9IMugRN2hbYnqC99DjtkFLapQNTQeg0IZ6dOYAqbao0KYlj@8uf/DmZiwlP@88hK0zTwNpY7AIAiy6vDybLYePTsQAZ8ytyTZWeJo0NIKQwYPjS@Z5LPcLZ2riPqKiODPnqulec6zp3bY1gmBOSix3DkMkkcdTptRcw8xXdBIYhJvIVhXqOl4bEhNS9B3a/MfDUPTEkuFJcYEhhqXQ/6IAeeW53hc2gccZRuFR2DyX5ZFtXWzy@vRs@efTmoSQ/mH@NCRutAhyqerzQplKDTWSsKAjBxybA9rtxeRlVrYvOpOhYGWFEn8XF4m4xS/xliqv4jc50Xqr4gf8HPcWPaqb6oB9@AA))

Comment: In real life, I’d use `31-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)` instead of `(int)(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2))`, but it’s not shorter. Unless you use `import static` in the header, which might stretch the rules too far.

Comment: @Holger It actually is shorter, although only by 1 byte. Thanks, I'll edit it in. :)

Comment: I just tried to convert your first variant’s loop to a stream solution, with success: `n -> n.toString(n,2).chars().reduce(0,(r,c)->r*3+c-47)`

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
b€>3β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/6VHTGjvjc5v@/zcyAAA)

```
b       binary
 €>     increment each
   3β   base 3
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
2в>3β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6MImO@Nzm4AMAwA)

Comment: `S` works for `€` too.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
3#.1+#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jZX1DLWVrf5rcilwpSZn5CsopCkZKGTqGRlA@WkKhkbGpjC2pbGFkSnXfwA)

Thanks Galen Ivanov for -4 bytes! I really need to improve my J golfing skill...

Comment: 7 bytes: `3#.1+#:`
[TIO](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jZX1DLWVrf5rcilwpSZn5CsopCkZKGTqGRlA@WkKhkbGpjC2pbGFkSnXfwA)

Comment: Also thanks for the template, I need something to learn about `: 0`.

Comment: The template is not mine, I forgot who's its author.

Comment: That would be me :)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 43 bytes

```r
function(n)(n%/%2^(x=0:log2(n))%%2+1)%*%3^x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPUyNPVV/VKE6jwtbAKic/3QgopKmqaqRtqKmqpWocV/E/TcPS2MLIVPM/AA)

Uses the standard base conversion trick in R, increments, and then uses a dot product with powers of `3` to convert back to an integer.

Thanks to [@user2390246](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66252/user2390246) for dropping 12 bytes!

Comment: Because the conversion to binary is not the final output, the order of the digits doesn't matter. So instead of floor(log(n)):0 you can do 0:log(n) and save some bytes: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPUyNPVV/VKE6jwtbAKic/3QgopKmqaqRtqKmqpWocV/E/TcPS2MLIVPM/AA)

Comment: @user2390246 of course, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

```apl
3⊥1+2⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wTjR11LDbWNgOSj3sWH1hs@6loElFAw5EpTMAJiUyC2VAAShgYgEQMA)

```
    2⊥⍣¯1  binary
  1+       go guess
3⊥         base 3
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
ḃ+₁ᵐ~ḃ₃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GOZu1HTY0Pt06oAzIfNTX//29oZGz6PwoA)

#### Explanation

Not that you really need one, but…

```
ḃ            To binary
 +₁ᵐ         Map increment
    ~ḃ₃      From ternary
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
f=->x{x>0?x%2+1+3*f[x/2]:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCsIwFET3/xQBcWOtZiYmVsF4kJCFisGlSIVI27NHpHH3ePPm9b5@Skmn1uche33OSzZozCqFvGU86qkErBeq9YrCGfZiqzFymMl1Al1XLaxIQEBTa1jtfg/T8W@woyUcJG7ul9tjGPvxqVLo41S@)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(''.join('12'[c>'0']for c in bin(n)[2:]),3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNDoIwEEb3nmISF20TYzpTW5FEL4IsANOI0SkhbDx9hRqLy/e@n@E93QNT9OdrfDav9tYAlz1PUoj9I/QsBZKouovQovZhhA56hnb2rCoqa7UzKg7jPAAvUcEWaPNDWvCY0abUZD4t7IrMqFNfr/skCHGtkEkvaLX7fzIFfT0eyBI6jB8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 19 bytes

```
FromBase&3@1&`+@Bin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7360oP9cpsThVzdjBUC1B28EpM@@/X2pqSnG0SkFBcnosV0BRZl5JSGpxiTNQVXF0mo5CtKGOkY6pjqWOoYGOkYGOoZExkGNsYWQaG/sfAA)

This is a composition of three functions:

- `FromBase&3`
- `` 1&`+ ``
- `Bin`

This first converts to binary (`Bin`), increments it (`` 1&`+ ``), then converts to ternary (`FromBase&3`).

### Alternatives

Non-pointfree, 21 bytes: `{FromBase[Bin!_+1,3]}`

Without builtins, 57 bytes: `Sum@{_*3^(#_-Iota!_-1)}@{If[_>0,$[_/2|Floor]'(1+_%2),[]]}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 36 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`^(1+)\1
$1;1
^
1
+`1;
;111
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLOyFOw1BbM8aQS8XQ2pArjssQKGRozWVtaGjIZfj/vyUA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert from decimal to unary.

```
+`^(1+)\1
$1;1
```

Repeatedly divmod by 2, and add 1 to the result of the modulo.

```
^
1
```

Add 1 to the first digit too.

```
+`1;
;111
```

Convert from unary-encoded base 3 to unary.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```js
¤cÄ n3
¤      // Convert the input to a base-2 string,
 c     // then map over it as charcodes.
  Ä    // For each item, add one to its charcode
       // and when that's done,
    n3 // parse the string as a base 3 number.
```

Takes input as a number, outputs a number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CS5MMtCnnG//9bAgA)

Comment: Damnit! Why didn't I think of that? Nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
BQ3_ZA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3ynQOD7K8f9/SwA)

Saved **5** bytes thanks to Giuseppe and another one thanks to Luis Mendo.

Old 7 byte answer:

```
YBQc3ZA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9IpMNk4yvH/f0sA)

#### Explanation:

```
YB        % Convert to binary string
  Q       % Increment each element
   c      % Convert ASCII values to characters
    3     % Push 3
     ZA   % Convert from base 3 to decimal.
```

---

Old one for 12 bytes:

```
BQtz:q3w^!Y*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3ymwpMqq0Lg8TjFS6/9/SwA)

Oh my, that was messy... So is this: `BQ3GBn:q^!Y*.

#### Explanation:

```
               % Implicit input
B              % Convert to binary vector
 Q             % Increment all numbers
  t            % Duplicate
   z           % Number of element in vector
    :          % Range from 1 to that number
     q         % Decrement to get the range from 0 instead of 1
      3        % Push 3
       w       % Swap order of stack
        ^      % Raise 3 to the power of 0, 1, ...
         !     % Transpose
          Y*   % Matrix multiplication
               % Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 128 bytes

```cs
using System;using System.Linq;i=>{int z=0;return Convert.ToString(i,2).Reverse().Select(a=>(a-47)*(int)Math.Pow(3,z++)).Sum();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBS8QwEIXPya@YY@J2w27rolLbi@DJhWIFD@IhxHQ3sE0wSVfc0t8ep1LQEMLM8N6bj6iwVkGlIRh7gPY7RN2X9H8nnoz9LCkNUUajQJ1kCNB4d/Cy70dKlvnZmQ/YS2NZiB7db@8g/SHwkVJYzuNg1b2xMQN8auiqZKp6xBou1ab0Og7ewoOzZ@2jeHHtbw4zWc7Fs8Zh0IyLVp@0ikxWNZPr6xt@xTCA72U8isZ9sSK7rFYcZUPPeDmlkhLSOa@lOi5gYIceARY6AEJQQmYKC9VMJho5r0IZn90EiYI7afHqTdT4GZp1zPI/QM5LmDMmineiKW1TnnbpLm03Kd@kbV5gU9zmux8)

I am counting `System` because i use `Convert` and `Math`.

Comment: Select gives you the index as optional parameter. So you could get rid of your `z` variable. Also in the expression body you could get rid of the `{`, `}` and `return` statements. So something like this `n=>Convert.ToString(n,2).Reverse().Select((x,i)=>(x-47)*Math.Pow(3,i)).Sum();`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```python
lambda i:int(''.join(`int(x)+1`for x in bin(i)[2:]),3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoQwDEDRq2Rng2GwKcJMwZOoYEWKGbQVcaGnr@3yv8U/nmuNgZPvhrS5fV4ciJVwqar6/KMENZW4sdaTjyfcIAHmzII92xHJYCruiveamFr6kW6IG9Jscpgvt6M9zrwBrxymFw)

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <strike>84</strike> 64 Bytes

[Try it online!!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEEDRq7QQcshF0SosOoo0NlIQo5i1ic5utvnw4Ict5HEOpe5im3bPlZOC4RE4rWRx51@a7OYrXE4y1vNNMUmBzZmiiRRoSbLualV4UNkRQPWqa0G/2ckBdP4A)

**ORIGINAL Code**

```
function f($n){$b=decbin($n);echo base_convert($b+str_repeat('1',strlen($b)),3,10);}
```

[Try it online!!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRU8jSrU5Mz8hWSEotT45Pz88pSi0o0ikuKSoo0UlKTkzLzQEp0DA10jAw1dYyBDE3r2v9pGpaa1v8B)

**Thanks to Cristoph**, less bytes if ran with php -R

```
function f($n){echo base_convert(strtr(decbin($n),10,21),3,10);}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($n){
$b=decbin($n);                    #Convert the iteger to base 2
echo base_convert(                  #base conversion PHP function
    $b+str_repeat('1',strlen($b)),  #It adds to our base 2 number
    3,                              #a number of the same digits length
    10);                            #with purely '1's
}
```

Comment: Here is when i see i have a loooogn way to go at programming....had no idea of the existence of `strtr`

Comment: Will do!!, sorry `<?="Will do!!"`

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>32</s> 27 bytes

```c
n(x){x=x?x%2+1+3*n(x/2):0;}
```

Based on [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729)'s Java [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161625/79343). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9Po0KzusK2wr5C1UjbUNtYCyigb6RpZWBd@18hNzEzT0OzmksBCNLyizQy80oUMm0NrRUybQyNjYCUtrYmWFJBoaAIKJmmoaSaoqOkk6eRqalpDZYpKC0p1lBSgvHgqmLyQMoMjYxNNXHIWRpbGEEla7n@AwA).
Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for golfing 5 bytes.

Ungolfed version:

```c
n(x) { // recursive function; both argument and return type are implicitly int
    x = // implicit return
    x ? x % 2 + 1 + 3*n(x/2) // if x != 0 return x % 2 + 1 + 3*n(x/2) (recursive call)
    : 0; // else return 0
}
```

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by replacing the `return` with `x=` and reversing the ternary so the `!` is no longer necessary: `n(x){x=x?x%2+1+3*n(x/2):0;}`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with the communication toolbox, <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```matlab
@(x)(de2bi(x)+1)*3.^(0:log2(x))'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0JTIyXVKCkTyNA21NQy1ovTMLDKyU83Agpoqv9P0zDU5ErTMAIRpiDCEkQYGmj@BwA)

Converts the input to a binary vector using `de2bi`, and incrementing all numbers. Does matrix multiplication with a vertical vector of **3** raised to the appropriate powers: `1, 3, 9, ...`, thus getting the sum without an explicit call to `sum`.

Comment: While this is extremely clever, you can also do this for 32 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzKbE41SglNVkjWl1dISXVKCkTKKhtYhmrY6z5P03DUvM/AA "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: And with MATLAB you may even do `@(x)base2dec(de2bi(x)+49,3)` for 27 (a rare occasion where MATLAB is more lenient than Octave)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
B3m→ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/38k491HbpIc7uv///29pbGFkCgA)

#### Explanation

```
B3m→ḋ
    ḋ  Convert to base 2
  m→   Map increment
B3     Convert from base 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
ri2b:)3b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyjTKMlK0zjp/39LYwsjUwA)

#### Explanation

```
ri   e# Read input as an integer
2b   e# Convert to base 2. Gives a list containing 0 and 1
:)   e# Add 1 to each number in that list
3b   e# Convert list from base 3 to decimal. Implicitly display
```

Comment: I kinda like the `:)` ..

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 74 bytes

```
({<>(())<>({<({}[()])><>([{}]())<>})}(<>)){{}((({})()){}{}[{}])([][()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxCoBAEAO/kxQWKnbHfeS44iwEUSxsw759DTaBGSb7O85nOu5xZUKlAqRXBYoGdlZTU/TfBwOlklIALmircOmAaP1/mDPnZd0@)

### "Readable" version

```
({<>(())<>
  ({
    <({}[()])>
    <>
    ([{}]())
    <>
  })
}
# At this point we have a inverted binary string on the stack
(<>)
)
{
  {}
  (
    (({})()){}{}[{}]
  )
  ([][()])
}{}
```

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYsxCoBAEAO/kxQWKnbHfeS44iwEUSxsw759DTaBGSb7O85nOu5xZUKlAqRXBYoGdlZTU/TfBwOlklIALmircOmAaP1/mDPnZd0@ "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```ruby
f=->x{x>0?x%2+3*f[x>>1]+1:0}
```

black magic, no idea how it works

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W166iusLOwL5C1UjbWCstusLOzjBW29DKoPZ/QWlJsUJadHpqSbFeSX58Zux/IwMA)

Comment: the left shift gets binary digits right to left, and x%2+1 increases the binary value according to the spec.

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 117 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_number][T    T   T   _Retrieve][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_OUTER_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S N
_Push_2][T  S T T   _Modulo][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer_division][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_OUTER_LOOP][N
S S N
_Create_Label_INNER_LOOP][S S S T   T   N
_Push_3][T  S S N
_Multiply][T    S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S T N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_PRINT_AND_EXIT][S N
T   _Swap][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_INNER_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_PRINT_AND_EXIT][S N
T   _Swap][T    N
S T _Output_integer_to_STDOUT]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoBADAPPySvyBkXQ54gs6E1Q8Pm16aJtGUI7ffbjbte5bi1CErNzQLj4bSSIEOBEU8W@LSmjVdZ/Xkr71RJgWqF6TiBiGedhegE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

#### Explanation in pseudo-code:

I first converted the recursive function `int f(int n){return n<1?0:n%2+1+3*f(n/2);}` to its iterative form (in pseudo-code):

```
Integer n = STDIN as integer
Add starting_value 0 to the stack
function OUTER_LOOP:
  while(true){
    Add n%2+1 to the stack
    n = n/2
    if(n == 0):
      Jump to INNER_LOOP
    Else:
      Jump to next iteration OUTER_LOOP

function INNER_LOOP:
  while(true){
    n = 3*n
    n = n + Value at the top of the stack (the ones we calculated with n%2+1)
    Swap top two items
    Check if the top is now 0 (starting value):
      Jump to PRINT_AND_EXIT
    Else:
      Swap top two items back
      Jump to next iteration INNER_LOOP

function PRINT_AND_EXIT:
  Swap top two items back
  Print top to STDOUT as integer
  Exit program with error: Exit not defined
```

And I then implemented this iterative approach in the stack-based language Whitespace, using it's default stack.

#### Example runs:

**Input: `1`**

```
Command    Explanation                   Stack           Heap    STDIN   STDOUT   STDERR

SSSN       Push 0                        [0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)             [0,0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)             [0,0,0]
TNTT       Read STDIN as integer         [0,0]           {0:1}   1
TTT        Retrieve                      [0,1]           {0:1}
NSSSN      Create Label OUTER_LOOP       [0,1]           {0:1}
 SNS       Duplicate top (1)             [0,1,1]         {0:1}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,1,1,2]       {0:1}
 TSTT      Modulo top two (1%2)          [0,1,1]         {0:1}
 SSSTN     Push 1                        [0,1,1,1]       {0:1}
 TSSS      Add top two (1+1)             [0,1,2]         {0:1}
 SNT       Swap top two                  [0,2,1]         {0:1}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,2,1,2]       {0:1}
 TSTS      Int-divide top two (1/2)      [0,2,0]         {0:1}
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)             [0,2,0,0]       {0:1}
 NTSN      If 0: Go to Label INNER_LOOP  [0,2,0]         {0:1}
 NSSN      Create Label INNER_LOOP       [0,2,0]         {0:1}
  SSSTTN   Push 3                        [0,2,0,3]       {0:1}
  TSSN     Multiply top two (0*3)        [0,2,0]         {0:1}
  TSSS     Add top two (2+0)             [0,2]           {0:1}
  SNT      Swap top two                  [2,0]           {0:1}
  SNS      Duplicate top (0)             [2,0,0]         {0:1}
  NTSTN    If 0: Jump to Label PRINT     [2,0]           {0:1}
  NSSTN    Create Label PRINT            [2,0]           {0:1}
   SNT     Swap top two                  [0,2]           {0:1}
   TNST    Print top to STDOUT           [0]             {0:1}           2
                                                                                  error
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoBADAPPySvyBZ8ksqA3QcHn16SLtmUI7fTZj3tc57qNKkl0e0Ck@G0kiBCQxFDNuW3JMSr735fWfrUFhFGomQ1ULS8) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).
Stops with error: Exit not defined.

**Input: `4`**

```
Command    Explanation                   Stack           Heap    STDIN   STDOUT   STDERR

SSSN       Push 0                        [0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)             [0,0]
SNS        Duplicate top (0)             [0,0,0]
TNTT       Read STDIN as integer         [0,0]           {0:4}   4
TTT        Retrieve                      [0,4]           {0:4}
NSSSN      Create Label OUTER_LOOP       [0,4]           {0:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (4)             [0,4,4]         {0:4}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,4,4,2]       {0:4}
 TSTT      Modulo top two (4%2)          [0,4,0]         {0:4}
 SSSTN     Push 1                        [0,4,0,1]       {0:4}
 TSSS      Add top two (0+1)             [0,4,1]         {0:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                  [0,1,4]         {0:4}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,1,4,2]       {0:4}
 TSTS      Int-divide top two (4/2)      [0,1,2]         {0:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (2)             [0,1,2,2]       {0:4}
 NTSN      If 0: Go to Label INNER_LOOP  [0,1,2]         {0:4}
 NSNSN     Jump to Label OUTER_LOOP      [0,1,2]         {0:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (2)             [0,1,2,2]       {0:4}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,1,2,2,2]     {0:4}
 TSTT      Modulo top two (2%2)          [0,1,2,0]       {0:4}
 SSSTN     Push 1                        [0,1,2,0,1]     {0:4}
 TSSS      Add top two (0+1)             [0,1,2,1]       {0:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                  [0,1,1,2]       {0:4}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,1,1,2,2]     {0:4}
 TSTS      Int-divide top two (2/2)      [0,1,1,1]       {0:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (1)             [0,1,1,1,1]     {0:4}
 NTSN      If 0: Go to Label INNER_LOOP  [0,1,1,1]       {0:4}
 NSNSN     Jump to Label OUTER_LOOP      [0,1,1,1]       {0:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (1)             [0,1,1,1,1]     {0:4}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,1,1,1,1,2]   {0:4}
 TSTT      Modulo top two (1%2)          [0,1,1,1,1]     {0:4}
 SSSTN     Push 1                        [0,1,1,1,1,1]   {0:4}
 TSSS      Add top two (1+1)             [0,1,1,1,2]     {0:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                  [0,1,1,2,1]     {0:4}
 SSSTSN    Push 2                        [0,1,1,2,1,2]   {0:4}
 TSTS      Int-divide top two (1/2)      [0,1,1,2,0]     {0:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)             [0,1,1,2,0,0]   {0:4}
 NTSN      If 0: Go to Label INNER_LOOP  [0,1,1,2,0]     {0:4}
 NSSN      Create Label INNER_LOOP       [0,1,1,2,0]     {0:4}
  SSSTTN   Push 3                        [0,1,1,2,0,3]   {0:4}
  TSSN     Multiply top two (0*3)        [0,1,1,2,0]     {0:4}
  TSSS     Add top two (2+0)             [0,1,1,2]       {0:4}
  SNT      Swap top two                  [0,1,2,1]       {0:4}
  SNS      Duplicate top (1)             [0,1,2,1,1]     {0:4}
  NTSTN    If 0: Jump to Label PRINT     [0,1,2,1]       {0:4}
  SNT      Swap top two                  [0,1,1,2]       {0:4}
  NSNN     Jump to Label INNER_LOOP      [0,1,1,2]       {0:4}
  SSSTTN   Push 3                        [0,1,1,2,3]     {0:4}
  TSSN     Multiply top two (2*3)        [0,1,1,6]       {0:4}
  TSSS     Add top two (1+6)             [0,1,7]         {0:4}
  SNT      Swap top two                  [0,7,1]         {0:4}
  SNS      Duplicate top (1)             [0,7,1,1]       {0:4}
  NTSTN    If 0: Jump to Label PRINT     [0,7,1]         {0:4}
  SNT      Swap top two                  [0,1,7]         {0:4}
  NSNN     Jump to Label INNER_LOOP      [0,1,7]         {0:4}
  SSSTTN   Push 3                        [0,1,7,3]       {0:4}
  TSSN     Multiply top two (7*3)        [0,1,21]        {0:4}
  TSSS     Add top two (1+21)            [0,22]          {0:4}
  SNT      Swap top two                  [22,0]          {0:4}
  SNS      Duplicate top (0)             [22,0,0]        {0:4}
  NTSTN    If 0: Jump to Label PRINT     [22,0]          {0:4}
  NSSTN    Create Label PRINT            [22,0]          {0:4}
   SNT     Swap top two                  [0,22]          {0:4}
   TNST    Print top to STDOUT           [0]             {0:4}           22
                                                                                  error
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoBADAPPySvyCD8ksqA3QcHn16SLtmUI7fTZj3tc57qNKkl0e0Ck@G0kiBCQxFDNuW3JMSr735fWfrUFhFGomQ1ULS8) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).
Stops with error: Exit not defined.

Comment: At this point, why not write assembly? Also I have a slightly simpler iterative method in my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161833/17360

Comment: I've simplified my python pseudocode further.

Comment: @qwr Your Python code is almost the same as the displayed Java code. Java is just more verbose and error-prone. The only difference is that my Java code is a nested while-loop, and yours is separated. I could do that as well in Java, but since it's nested in Whitespace I chose to write it as such in the Java pseudo-code as well. Also, Whitespace doesn't have any way to know the number of items left on the stack, which is why I push the 0 at the start, and in the INNER_LOOP part of the code do: swap, check if 0, swap back. Nice Assembly answer, though. So I've +1-ed it. :)

Comment: I still think you can get rid of the `n < 1` check by pushing values until n is 0 and then popping them until you hit your boundary value (0). The stack depth doesn't need to be stored explicitly and there shouldn't even need to be swapping (if you mean swapping the top two values like in lisp)

Comment: @qwr "_I still think you can get rid of the n < 1 check by pushing values until n is 0_" Umm.. checking if `n < 1` (or `n == 0`) IS pushing values until `n` is 0.. Or am I misinterpreting something here.. :S "_The stack depth doesn't need to be stored explicitly_" In Java it does, otherwise I can't create the array. I could have used a `java.util.Stack` instead, but I just used an array to make it less verbose. In Whitespace the stack is of undefined size.

Comment: As for the swap: Whitespace has no way to know the size of the stack left, and just continues until you tell it to stop, or until it errors out, so I need the swap and check if I've reached the `0` I pushed before starting the loop it to know when to stop (I could have used `-1` and a check_if_negative instead, but it would be 1 more byte). Without that swap and check it would just continue looping and errors when it tries to do the `Add_top_two` action inside the `INNER_LOOP` with only a single item left on the stack, in which case I can't print to STDOUT anymore, hence the check.

Comment: @qwr I've removed the Java code because it only seemed to confuse you, and added actual pseudo-code instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
b›3β
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=b%E2%80%BA3%CE%B2&inputs=9&header=&footer=)

```
b    # Binary
 ›   # Increment
  3β # From base 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 14 bytes

```
L,BBu1€+B]3$Bb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8mp1PBR0xptp1hjFaek////W/7LLyjJzM8r/q@rm5lbkJOZnFkCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
¤£°XÃn3
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=pKOwWMNuMw==&input=OA==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
É¥ê4¼⌐○
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=909d8834aca909&i=9%0A1235&a=1&m=2)

This one is pretty straightforward.  After unpacking, and commenting, the program looks like this.

```
:B  Convert to bits
{^m Increment each
3|b Base-3 convert
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f 0=0
f a=1+mod a 2+3*f(div a 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdNDkAwEAbQvVN8Sz8TaaeRsOgRnEBEJqHRUARx/WL33izXMq1rjA7KqsRBrC7CPkLAhcldOvrndxaD@A0WQY52QHqcfrtRwmXoNDFV1JBWxIo0my@m5qqPLw)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8

```
ihMjQ2 3
```

How to eliminate the space and make the `Q` implicit?

[Pyth online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ihMjQ2%203&input=9&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A5%0A9%0A10%0A20%0A1235%0A93825&debug=0).

Comment: I believe this is actually 8 bytes

Comment: @hakr14 Yes, you're right

Comment: *How to eliminate the space and make the `Q` implicit?* I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
$\+=(1+$_%2)*3**$b++,$_>>=1while$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWw1BbJV7VSFPLWEtLJUlbW0cl3s7O1rA8IzMnVSW@tvr/f0MjY9N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 66 bytes

```
[2~rd0<B]dsBxz1-si[1+z:tz0<T]dsTx0dsj[ljd1+dsj;tr3r^*+ljli>M]dsMxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxCsMgFEX3fEXnSsGnBJI27eAuhJBN0g6@xfAoQTOIQ3/darIcDvdw0eY@G/HzyAe1YFAxwS04Ayzd98SHuWxz5BhWQysCK/LYvfTvK6OV3EuXruOWDX7bbiQVwycFR@eFdER48s0uYWqAj7YBmuJFVLQVfQXwYzwIQp5BdqJK/gM)

`[2~rd0<B]dsBx` is a macro that uses `dc`'s quotient/remainder integer division, `~` to continuously break divide by two, breaking *n* down to individual binary bits on the stack. It will always leave one extra zero, so we subtract one from the stack depth and store this total length in `i` with `z1-si`.

`[1+z:tz0<T]dsTx` is a macro that adds one to whatever is on the stack, and then pops that value, storing it at index(stack depth) in array `t`. This basically means that if we started with the binary `1101`, `t` now holds `2, 1, 2, 2`, assuming 1-indexing. `0dsj` puts a zero on the stack so we don't get a stack empty error when we do our first addition, and it stores a zero in register `j` as well.

`[ljd1+dsj;tr3r^*+ljli>M]dsMx` is, unfortunately, a lot of counter nonsense. We need register `j` for two things - pull element `(j+1)` from array `t`, and multiply it by `3^j`. We start macro `M` by putting `j` on the stack and duplicating it. We increment the new copy, duplicate it, and store it back into `j`. With the copy of `(j+1)` we left behind, we pull from array `t`. Swap so that our original `j` is at the top of the stack, do the necessary base-three math with `3r^*`, add this 'bit' to our total, and then compare `j` with `i` to see if we still have more 'bits' to do. At the very end, we `p`rint.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 54 bytes

```
=DECIMAL(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(BASE(A1,2),1,2),0,1),3)
```

A fairly straightforward translation of the problem. Takes input from A1. I tried some cuter things with bit math like

```
=SUM(IF(ROW(1:31)<LOG(A1,2)+1,POWER(3,ROW(1:31)-1)*(1+MOD(BITRSHIFT(A1, ROW(1:31)-1),2))))
```

because nesting SUBSTITUTE always feels wasteful, but couldn't get nearly as short.

Comment: Try `+REPT(1,LEN(BASE(A1,2)))` instead of nesting `SUBSTITUTE`?

Comment: Or, even `+REPT(1,1+LOG(A2,2))`, since `REPT` ignores the non-integer portion of the number

Comment: It's a good suggestion but I couldn't make it work for the range covered by the test cases. The complete solution there is `=DECIMAL(REPT(1,1+LOG(A1,2))+BASE(A1,2),3)` which is only 43 bytes! But unfortunately it gets the wrong answer even for the  93825 test case, due to rounding error as it passes through a representation as a double, and I can't figure out how to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 7 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
£?☺å♥£F
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.3/JstxGWT.html?code=wqM_4pi6w6XimaXCo0Y%3D&args=OQ%3D%3D)

Explanation

```
£? # Push the first stack value in binary.
☺  # Push literal 1
å  # Push the second stack value with all characters arithmetically shifted by the first stack value.
♥  # Push literal 3
£F # Push the second stack value in base first stack value converted to decimal.
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86, 26 bytes

Rewrite of the recursive formula as a tail-recursive stack function, since  function calls are expensive. Uses __fastcall convention (input in `ecx`, output in `eax`).

<s>The `cmp %esp,%ebp`/`je sum1` branch is done to prevent an extra multiplication of 3 from occurring. It might save bytes to avoid this branch.</s> Reordering the multiplication makes this unnecessary and saves 4 bytes.

```
.section .text
.globl main
main:
        mov     $10, %ecx

start:
        mov     %esp, %ebp          # Save sp 
build:
        mov     %ecx, %eax
        and     $1, %eax
        inc     %eax                # n%2 + 1
        push    %eax                # push n%2 + 1
        sar     %ecx                # n >>= 1
        jnz     build               # do while (n)
        
        xor     %eax, %eax          # sum = 0
sum0:
        lea     (%eax,%eax,2),%eax  # sum *= 3
        pop     %ebx
        add     %ebx, %eax          # pop stack, add to sum
        cmp     %esp, %ebp
        jnz     sum0                # do while stack non-empty


        ret
```

Hexdump:

```
00000039  89 e5 89 c8 83 e0 01 40  50 d1 f9 75 f5 31 c0 8d  |.......@P..u.1..|
00000049  04 40 5b 01 d8 39 e5 75  f6 c3                    |.@[..9.u..|
```

---

Assembly-friendly python:

```
stack = []
while n:
    stack.append(n%2 + 1)
    n //= 2

while stack:
    s *= 3
    s += stack.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
x->parse(Int,map(x->x+1,bin(x)),3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0LXriCxqDhVwzOvRCc3sUADKFChbaiTlJmnUaGpqWOs@T81L4XLoTgjv1whTcNS8z8A)

Tho it seems like this is the cool way

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
f(n)=n<1?0:n%2+1+3f(n÷2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/TSNP0zbPxtDewCpP1UjbUNsYKHJ4u5Hmf4fijPxyhTQNS83/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 37 bytes

```sh
a=3#$[[##2]$1];echo $[a+${a//[01]/1}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnNCgIhEADg@zzFoHML0VEWCqkXEQ@SAwqxQrsQFD27/Rw/vufW5qP1m@BdSsUesQ7cZEdjUFFXEeXaBpr1JzQXVLOcg6aUtPaZOMf/UyoHehVrk@Ns@Z1nHatMBg8LnIAdeAfswxfh6JcP)

- `$[...]` is another (deprecated?) form of `$(( ))`
- `[#n]` in arithmetic expansion sets the output base but includes the base in output (so you get `2#1001`), `[##n]` omits the base in output: `1001`.
- `n#` in arithmetic expansion sets the input base
- `${var//pat/rep}` replaces all matches of `pat` with `rep`.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 43 bytes

```
func n(x){return x<1?0:x%2+1+3*n(int(x/2))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrLCsIwFET39yuyqJBYxMzEpFV8fIuIggh3UVoMiN8eSVydOcO5vl@lPBa9GbXZfab7vExq8hEXf8gr9ujDWu1TZ5u3dO5bOn9S28EVmM3ZUFgxSGwWZF@ZRoFvvxe2QUDA0CpEn2oZRv4dO0YiQX4)

I discovered that `AWK` has `rshift` and `lshift` functions.  They use more bytes than just doing a divide and cast, but might be useful sometime. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 28

```bash
dc -e?2op|tr 01 12|dc -e3i?p
```

Input read from STDIN.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxDoAgEAR7X7GFrQkcIdFY@BEbhTPYeAQo@TsSC6ebSeY8cmiXJBTOxR2ZcT/QIFgs0AqkoMl0MTPZFV4GdNgFwfgvFXvzDhNvJLGWBKX7Vb9k7i02Lw@3Fw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 25 bytes

```
f(n)=if(n,n%2+1+3*f(n\2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P00jT9M2E0jq5KkaaRtqG2sB2TFGmpr/EwsKcio18hR07RQKijLzSoBMJRBHSQGkR1NHIdpQR8FIR8FUR8FSR8HQAMgBYkMjY5CAsYWRaazmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 50 bytes

```
+<,[[>-]++>[<]<[>+[<]<]>>-]>[>]<-<<[>[-<+++>]<<]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f20YnOtpON1Zb2y7aJtYm2k4bRMXaAYXsou1ibXRtgGLRujbaQAWxNkAJvf//uQA)

Input and output as code points, and assumes arbitrary size cells otherwise it can't get past n=31.

Answer (score 0):

## Go, 54 bytes

```
func f(n int)(o int){if n>0{o=n%2+1+3*f(n>>1)};return}
```

Base solution is the same as the one that everyone else uses.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCoMwEEX3OUUQCkmF6kyqtZR6hl5BxEhonUiIK/Hs1tZ0k64G3v//TW/XsWmfTd/xoTHEzDBa53miB5@seqKWa0HckJfCfs9sNKc6n@2dDphCqo5boa5BLjfX@cnRss8@NiH5zNimOj3ctn2R0AKk5FnGMcK440uEi9BWEb/uvKxiex48eewPAQLEE1ThCxR5@f9JVfjL4YwFQglsWd8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃ⁺3b
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4MyVFMiU4MSVCQTNiJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9OSZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
ḃ⁺3b  # Implicit input
ḃ     # Convert to binary
 ⁺    # Increment each
  3b  # Convert from base-3
      # Implicit output
```